# Return actual string value from LINQ SQLite query C#

Tags: c#, ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios

Im currently creating a login system using SQLite using C# on Xamarin.ios. The issue Im having is that a send in a hashed password to the database which works fine. On the login side of it, I need to get the actually hashed value back so I can run a method which checks the returned value against the user inputted value.

The problem im having is that the query doesnt actually return a value as all and I dont actually understand what I get back from the query. I run FirstOrDefault to make sure I only get the email and password back whcih the user has enetered for their email. However, because I do not get a string value back, Im not sure on how ti put it into a method to check the hash value.

Hopefully this makes sense. This is the code which runs the query:

```
public void UserLogin()
    {
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "PmApp.db3");
        var connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);


        string loginEmail = loginEmailInput.Text;
        string loginPass = loginPasswordInput.Text;

        var emailExists = (from s in connection.Table<SQLiteTables.LoginInfo>()
                           where s.Email.Equals(loginEmail)
                           where s.Password.Equals(loginPass)
                           select s).FirstOrDefault();


        Console.WriteLine(emailExists); //This is just to see what value gets returned
    }
```

And this is the value that is returned:

```
2018-05-16 15:57:50.401 SQLite[15735:8043670] SQLite.SQLiteTables+LoginInfo
```

Hopefully somebody can help.
Jamie

Comment: That's a row.  Look at its properties.

Comment: is Password stored as a hashed value or a plaintext value?

Comment: You are getting a set of data, not a string. as @SLaks said, you should inspect your variable

Comment: @Jason It is stored as a Hashed Value and I want the entire row but want to see the actual values of each row so that I can use a method to compare the returned hash value against the users inputted value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var loginInfo = (from s in connection.Table<SQLiteTables.LoginInfo>()
                       where s.Email.Equals(loginEmail)
                       select s).FirstOrDefault();

if (loginInfo != null) {
  var dbPass = loginInfo.Password;
  if (hash(dbPass) == hash(loginPass) {
    // hashed passwords match
  }
}
```

you could also do the hash first

```
var hashedPass = hash(loginPass);
var loginInfo = (from s in connection.Table<SQLiteTables.LoginInfo>()
                       where s.Email.Equals(loginEmail)
                       where s.Password.Equals(hashedPass)
                       select s).FirstOrDefault();

if (loginInfo != null) {
  // hashed passwords match
}
```

Comment: The first example would double hash the db password, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to return one column, try this :

```
var emailExists = (from s in connection.Table<SQLiteTables.LoginInfo>()
                       where s.Email.Equals(loginEmail)
                       where s.Password.Equals(loginPass)
                       select s.Email).FirstOrDefault();
```